# Getting $e$ closer than $0,001$?

Tags: series-expansion, summation

Everyone knows that $\sum \frac{1}{n!} =e$. How should I make a program in Wolfram Mathematica, that tells me, how many members I need from the sum, to get a number, with mistake smaller, than $0,001?$

I checked it manually, and the answer was, that I need to sum it until $n=6$ from $n=0$, so the output should be $7$. Any ideas? :)

Comment: show what you have tried so far. I assume you know functions like, `Sum` and `Table` ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice the partial sum can be expressed in terms of (incomplete) Gamma functions.

```
Sum[1/n!, {n, 0, k}]
```

> ```
> (E Gamma[1 + k, 1])/Gamma[1 + k]
> ```

So we can use this closed form in something like `FindRoot` and it should be pretty fast.

```
Ceiling[k /. FindRoot[E - Sum[1/n!, {n, 0, k}] == 1/1000, {k, 10}]] + 1
```

> ```
> 7
> ```

### Edit

Using `GammaRegularized` as J.M. mentioned in the comments, we can actually find a close guess and iterate a few times to find the exact answer.

To find the exact answer, we'd need to invert `GammaRegularized` with respect to its first input and I don't know how to do that. Instead we'll take the main term from its series, approximate that, and invert that to get a pretty good guess.

Using `Expand[Normal[Series[E - E GammaRegularized[x+1, 1], {x, ∞, 0}]]]`, we see

$$ e - \sum_{n = 0}^k \frac{1}{n!} \approx \frac{\exp(k - k\log k)(1/k)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} = \frac{e^k \, k^{-k}}{k\sqrt{2\pi k}}. $$

Applying [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we get

$$ e - \sum_{n = 0}^k \frac{1}{n!} \approx \frac{1}{k \, k!} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k)}. $$

So if we want to find when the partial sum comes within say $\epsilon$, a good guess will be $\Gamma^{-1}(1/\epsilon)$. This is found by inverting the above relation.

In practice, since `Gamma` grows so fast, it's better to use `LogGamma` instead. So the guess I'll be using is $\log\Gamma^{-1}(-\log\epsilon)$.

Now that we have our guess, we can just iterate until we find the first occurrence.

Also, as J.M. points out in the comments section, a better closed form for $e - \sum_{n=0}^k 1/n!$ is `E*GammaRegularized[guess, 0, 1]`. But it turns out it's even faster to just sum the factorials.

```
ESeriesTermCount[ε_] := Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 10000, guess, comp},

  guess = Ceiling[InverseFunction[LogGamma][-Log[ε]]];

  While[Not[(comp = E - Total[1/Range[0, guess]!] < ε) && 
          E - Total[1/Range[0, guess-1]!] >= ε],
    If[comp,
      guess--,
      guess++
    ]
  ];

  guess + 1
]
```

It seems to be pretty fast, but is only faster than conventional methods for really small values of ε.

```
ESeriesTermCount[0.001] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.014021, 7}
> ```

```
ESeriesTermCount[10^-400] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.028286, 211}
> ```

```
ESeriesTermCount[10^-1000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.03293, 450}
> ```

```
ESeriesTermCount[10^-10000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.668258, 3249}
> ```

### Edit 2

Final edit hopefully...

We can make this essentially constant time using J.M.'s idea of using `` SpecialFunctions`InverseLogGammaApprox ``.

Also note for large enough values it's faster to use `E*GammaRegularized[guess, 0, 1]`.

```
ESeriesTermCount2[ε_] := Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 10000, guess, comp},

  guess = Floor[SpecialFunctions`InverseLogGammaApprox[-Log[ε]]];

  While[Not[(comp = E GammaRegularized[guess + 1, 0, 1] < ε) && 
          E GammaRegularized[guess, 0, 1] >= ε],
    If[comp,
      guess--,
      guess++
    ]
  ];

  guess + 1
]
```

And the timings are really really fast:

```
ESeriesTermCount2[0.001] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.001375, 7}
> ```

```
ESeriesTermCount2[10^-400.] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000719, 211}
> ```

```
ESeriesTermCount2[10^-1000.] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000543, 450}
> ```

```
ESeriesTermCount2[10^-10000.] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.000637, 3249}
> ```

```
ESeriesTermCount2[10^-1000000000000000.] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.00061, 74419210652836}
> ```

Comment: Even simpler: `E GammaRegularized[1 + k, 1]`.

Comment: @J.M. Ah of course :p

Comment: It's too bad I cannot give another upvote, so here's two tips instead: 1. ``SpecialFunctions`InverseLogGammaApprox[x]`` gives a usable approximate inverse of `LogGamma[]`. 2. `E - E GammaRegularized[guess, 1]` is equivalent to `E GammaRegularized[guess, 0, 1]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the tips! I'll stay away from `InverseLogGammaApprox` in the answer just because it's not exposed in the `System` context.

Comment: Knew it'd give a boost. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Accumulate works too...

```
FirstPosition[Thread[Accumulate[1./(Range[0, 10]!)] - E > -0.001], True]

{7}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
First@NestWhile[ {#[[1]] + 1 , #[[2]] + 1/#[[1]]! } &, {0, -E}, 
  Abs[#[[2]]] > .001 &  ]
```

> 7

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party, but to me the fun of the problem is to approximate `E` without referring to `E`.  That includes not using $\Gamma$-related functions, at least in my understanding of $\Gamma$.  That means, I think, I might ought to implement factorial as a product; or perhaps since speed is not issue, at least in my approach, I could use `n!` with the understanding that it is such a product, irrespective of how it is implemented internally.

The difference between $\sum_{k=0}^n {1 \over k!}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {1 \over k!}$ is, by elementary considerations, bounded by ${1 \over k!\,k}$.  So the answer is given by

```
findn[error_] := Module[{n = 1},
  N@NestWhile[n++ #/n^2 &, 1, # > error &];
  n + 1
  ]

findn[0.001]
(*  7  *)
```

The estimate of ${1 \over k!\,k}$ is pretty good, good enough for estimating an integer.

```
e[n_] := Sum[1/k!, {k, 0, n}]

DiscretePlot[1/(n! n) - (E - e[n]), {n, 1, 15}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Actually the error is less than $(k+2)/[(k+1)!\,(k+1)]$, which is slightly smaller than $1/[k!\, k]$.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

To correct mistake as per comments

```
Catch@Scan[If[E - NSum[1/n!, {n, 0, #}] < 0.001, Throw[# + 1]] &, Range@100]
```

> 7

Comment: Wow, solutions without sum, thanks! :)

Comment: -1: This finds the first $m$ for which $\frac1{m!}<0.001$, which is not necessarily the same as the first $m$ for which $e-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{m-1}\frac1{n!}<0.001$. For example, if you replace $0.001$ with $0.2$, this code gives 3 though the correct answer is 4. @Atvin

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that